# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined...

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I've been getting the SQLSTATE[HY093] error but I can't seem to find the source of it. I am trying to INSERT a row into a database table using the parameters of a form.

I have echo'd all parameters from the form and they are all working and displaying correctly.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO members (mid, firstname, lastname, username, password, email, phone, street, location, gender, ccnumber, expirymonth, expiryyear) VALUES (NULL, :firstName, :lastName, :username, :password, :email, :phone, :street, :location, :gender, :ccnumber, :expmonth, :expyear);";  
$query = $dbConnect->prepare($q);
    $enc_password = crypt($password,$username);
    //echo 'It is: '.$enc_password.' ';
    //echo 'It is: '.$lastName.' ';
$query->bindParam(":firstname",$firstName);
$query->bindParam(":lastname",$lastName);
    $query->bindParam(":username",$username);
    $query->bindParam(":password",$enc_password);
    $query->bindParam(":email",$email);
$query->bindParam(":phone",$phone);
    $query->bindParam(":street",$street);
    $query->bindParam(":location",$location);
    $query->bindParam(":gender",$gender);
$query->bindParam(":ccnumber",$ccnumber);
    $query->bindParam(":expirymonth",$expmonth);
    $query->bindParam(":expiryyear",$expyear);
    //$query->debugDumpParams();
$result = $query->execute();
return $result;
```

Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

You have camel case:

```
$q = "INSERT ... :firstName, :lastName ...
```

and then lower case:

```
$query->bindParam(":firstname",$firstName);
$query->bindParam(":lastname",$lastName);
```

Looks like a case sensitivity issue.

You also have in your query:

```
:expmonth, :expyear
```

Yet you bind them as:

```
$query->bindParam(":expirymonth",$expmonth);
$query->bindParam(":expiryyear",$expyear);
```

Answer (score 0):

$query->bindParam(":expirymonth",$expmonth);
$query->bindParam(":expiryyear",$expyear);

I guess, you not defined 'expirymonth' and 'expiryyear' in your query.
Instead you call it ':expmonth, :expyear'